# How show that function is greater or equal zero?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions

Hi maths peoples I have question how you show that function is greater or equal to zero because I want show that function is dense function and this is one of two condition for show it is dense function.

Example we have function

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin(x) \text{ where } x \in \left[0, \pi\right]$$

How show this function $f(x) \geq 0$ ?

I make draw of sinus curve and see from zero to pi there is no value lower then zero... But I think when I say this in test teacher say wrong and laugh me after. How you do it like professional?

I think I check when function have no zero point in the interval? But how check it with this function?

$$f(x) = 0$$

$$0= \frac{1}{2}\cdot \sin(x) $$

$$0= \sin(x)$$

$$x = \arcsin(0) $$

$$x=0$$

But is this good? Because now know there is zero point and at this zero point function can go lower then zero..?

Comment: The proof that the sine function is positive between zero and pi is pretty fundamental and depends on the definition of sine. Which definition are you using--the high-school trigonometry definition, the y-coordinate of a point on the unit circle, the Maclaurin series series, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The sine function $\sin(\theta)$ is defined as the $y$-coordinate of the point corresponding to the angle $\theta$ on the unit circle. Since the angle from $0$ to $\pi$ sweeps out the top half of the semicircle (above or on the $x$-axis), it is not negative on any $\theta$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$.

Since $\frac{1}{2}$ is a positive constant, it will not change the sign of $\sin(\theta)$, and our previous answer holds.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the way to do this is work with bounds. For instance, in your case you know that for $x\in [0,\pi]$ we have that $0\leq \sin (x)\leq 1$ and so you cand bound your function $f$ in the following way$$
0\leq \sin (x)\leq 1
\Leftrightarrow 0\leq \frac12\sin (x)\leq \frac12\Leftrightarrow0\leq f(x)\leq \frac12
$$
and so, in particular, $f(x)\geq 0$.